# Is closing this as a translation request an over-reaction?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, specific-question

I was looking up how the grammar of こと works for "I like verbing" style sentences, as I wanted to have a valid example before putting it into my Anki. I came across [I like to do 'Verbs'](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47640/i-like-to-do-verbs) , which was closed as a translation request.

In my opinion, the question intended to ask about how to do "I like verbing", and gave four examples of sentences that involve "I like verbing".

I can understand a request to translate four totally unrelated sentences into Japanese as an ordinary translation request. I can also understand, that if the OP had posted twenty different examples and wanted them *all* to be translated, that someone might be trying to get the internet to do their homework for them. However, I don't see this as a problem here. If someone suspects homework cheating for this question, the best approach would be to only give one example of how to translate it.

I don't think this question is trivially googleable - when I was searching for "I like to こと", I got a lot of hits for websites written in Japanese for native speakers of Japanese trying to learn English grammar, rather than websites for native speakers of English learning Japanese grammar.